# best way for vue ant design components usage

Tags: vue.js, antd, ant-design-vue

i use vue2 ant design library, and have many components with same

```
import Vue from "vue"
import select from "select"
Vue.use(select)
```

is the best way usage like this, or i should import all ant design ui in app.vue?

Comment: i mean

import select from "ant-design-vue/lib/select"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a lot of antd component across your project it's recommended to register the `antd` plugin globally to make all the components available without using `import {someComponent,...} from 'ant-design-vue'` in every component :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Antd from 'ant-design-vue';
import App from './App';
import 'ant-design-vue/dist/antd.css';


Vue.use(Antd);//register all components

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>',
})
```

if you've a small project you could import the component locally when you need it like:

```
 import { Button, message } from 'ant-design-vue';
```

Comment: what happens if i call import and vue.use many times? 

is it affects performance?